# Android - Set custom dialog layout height to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a custom layout to show a dialog. Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/dialog_title_tv"
                android:text="Dialog Title"
                />
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select Country: "
                android:padding="8dp"
                />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select City: "
                android:padding="8dp"
                />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select Area: "
                android:padding="8dp"
                />
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/area_spinner"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It shows like this:

[image]

**However**, I want to set its height as WRAP_CONTENT. Currently, it's taking up the whole screen. How can I do this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: try keeping your done button inside scroll view and see if working

Comment: Have you tried using 0dp?

Comment: are you inflating it as alert dialog or popup window?

Comment: Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customlayout);

Comment: I personally don't like LinearLayouts for such simple UIs, if you are OK, I can post a layout code with RelativeLayouts, and yea, it will be much more optimized too. (FYI unnecessary nesting of views increases the cost of findViewById)

Comment: That would be great if you could post it. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this layout code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_title_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dialog Title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Enter Phone Number" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Select Country: " />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Select City: " />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Select Area: " />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/area_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/AddtoCart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Done" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1a000000"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="My Dialog"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_header"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:hint="Enter phone number"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/select_country_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Country:"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/country_spinner"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/country_spinner"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/select_city_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select City:"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/city_spinner"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/city_spinner"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="Select One"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/select_area_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Area:"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/area_spinner"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/area_spinner"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/area_spinner"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="Select One"
        android:layout_below="@+id/city_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="done"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/area_spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:textColor="#00f"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/area_spinner"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/done"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:textColor="#00f"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just copy paste the above XML code into your custom dialog layout.

> Though you have already marked an answer as correct, I am posting this
>   because of the following reasons

1. It has no nesting of views, which will increase the efficiency of your code.
2. It follows the Android Design Guidelines of building a Dialog Box
3. I feel, in stack overflow, providing an optimal solution instead of correcting bugs in existing solution is much more important.

> P.S: This is a non scroll view version of the dialog box. Since the
>   content is less. Please comment if you need scrollable version too. It
>   will have slightly different implementation which in turn will have
>   slightly different output.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try these:

- Set `android:layout_weight="1"` inside your `ScrollView`
- Set `android:layout_height` to some static height (in dp).
- Change parent from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`.